# SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Tags: sql-server

We are still running a legacy web application written in ASP which was hosted on Microsoft Server 2012. We were able to run it normally for more than a year until the application server automatically installed a windows update (KB4019215).

The database server is a SQL Server 2000 SP4 hosted on Windows Server 2003 Enterprise x64.

I was able to test the connection using ODBC application integraded into the system, but running it on the application prompts me the error "SQL Server does not exist or access denied".

I tried hosting it to another web server but it still shows the same error.

I'm confused if the problem is in the web server or database server.

How can I check where the error comes from?

Answer (score 1):

We already solved this problem. It was a Firewall issue with the host and virtual server.

Both Database and Application servers are hosted on a different virtual machine and base OS. We both disable firewall and anti virus to make sure there is no problem with the database or the application itself.

For now our priority is to make the web application up again.